# Error while upgrade MFC C++ project from VS 2008 to 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, mfc, visual-studio-2015

I have old project from VC++ 6.0, upgraded to VS2008 and fix some error then it compile success. But after upgrade from VS2008 to VS2013 or VS2015,
I get 753 error like:

```
1>  bitbuf.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(166): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(166): error C2062: type 'void' unexpected
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(312) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ATL::CComPtrBase<T>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(166): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(167): error C2059: syntax error : '{'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(167): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(334): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(351): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(358): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(364): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(391): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(399): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(411): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'Swap'
```

753 error from atlcomcli.h

I also try with VS2010, different error but still don't know where to fix

```
1>  bitbuf.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(117): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(131) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::numeric_limits<_Ty>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(118): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(224): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(225): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(289): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(290): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(355): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(356): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(419): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(420): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(482): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(483): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(545): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(546): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(611): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(612): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(739): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(740): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(804): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(805): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(869): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(870): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(934): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(935): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1062): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1063): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1127): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1128): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1193): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1194): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1260): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1261): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1327): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits(1328): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>  curve.cpp
1>  edittext.cpp
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you googled for the SWAP method to see what the function parameters are now? Compare that with what you are using in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few day, I find out that I have defined Swap function in my code, it going to conflict with Swap function in atlcomcli.h, then I rename my swap function and everything going work fine.